# How many possible combinations can be made of two characters from $62$ characters?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to make combinations to create an encryption system. Can you please tell me how to calculate how many possible combinations can be made of two characters from $62$ characters. Characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9.

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: Can the characters be equal? If yes, the number is $62^2$ if not, $62 \times 61$

Comment: If you care about order, the amount of character strings of length $2$, from $62$ characters is simply $62\cdot 61$

Comment: The title reflects your effort pretty accurately.

Answer (score 1):

In computer science, a *word* is a string of zero or more characters.  Assuming that repetition is permitted, some two character words in your alphabet include AA, 44, 65, 7b, n8, jk, cP, DL, Ez.

**Hint:** It often helps to consider a simpler problem.

How many two-character words can be constructed using the three-character alphabet $\{a, b, c\}$?

If repetition is permitted (which seems to me to be the most natural interpretation of the problem), we obtain 
$$\begin{array}{c c c} 
aa & ba & ca\\ 
ab & bb & cb\\ 
ac & bc & cc 
\end{array}$$
There are nine such words since for each of the three ways the first character can be selected, there are three choices for the second character.

If repetition is not permitted, we obtain 
$$\begin{array}{c c c}
& ba & ca\\
ab & & cb\\
ac & bc 
\end{array}
$$
There are six such words since for each of the three ways the first character can be selected, there are two permissible ways to choose the second character as the first character cannot be repeated.

You should be able to solve your problem by reasoning analogously with your $62$ character alphabet.